# How can I see the output of console.log()?

Tags: javascript

I am using this code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
 console.log("hello world");
</script>
```

How can I see the output of `console.log()`?

I searched on Google but did not find a solution.

Comment: Press F12, check the "Console" tab.

Answer (score 7):

You can open the error console, depending on your browser. (Ctrl+Shift+J in Firefox, or F12 in Chrome, for example). Most browsers have the console hidden in their developer tools.

Comment: Didn't know :D Only had FF to try.

Comment: Is there any way to show console logs in browser directly in cases where the developer tools is disabled?

Answer (score 4):

The  `console.log();` statement prints anything in the browser console.

Look for `Developer Tools` or Simply `Tools` menu in all major browsers.

If you are using  Google Chrome the press `Cntrl+shift+j` to see console.

In Firefox, press `Ctrl+Shift+I` and click on Console to view the console on Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

You need to view the result in the console. Open the console.

Also, you have a problem with your code.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
console.log("hello world");
</script>
```

Is not valid. Remove the spaces in the script tag, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("hello world");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

press F12 in google chrome and click on console to see the output

Comment: But I cant see any thing.  

I can see 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: u need to post more code or whole file...there is something else wrong

Answer (score -1):

1. Open firefox
2. Go to tools and then add-on.
3. Search and install an add-on named "firebug"
4. before reloading your page open firebug and go to console tab.
   You will see your desired result. If you have chrome then its already there. just use it

Answer (score -1):

first of all `console.log()` of javascript cannot be outputed in your..

you need the javascript console to output it

first

press F12 then click the console label

before refreshing the browser to see your output..

but if your `console.log()` alternatives for browser is `document.write();`

Answer (score -1):

You can add a chrome extension named "console log viewer" and then you can see the logs even without opening the developer tool

Answer (score -1):

For Chrome browser follow these steps:

1. click on *More tools* on the right side of the top
2. click on *Developer tools*
3. click on *console*