# Google Hangouts bot not returning any results

Tags: google-apps-script, bots, google-hangouts

So I'm trying to build a Scrabble bot that accepts the available set of letters, uses the [anagramica API](http://www.anagramica.com/api) & is supposed to return the available combination of words.

Here's what I've been able to code, so far -

```
/**
 * Responds to a MESSAGE event in Hangouts Chat.
 *
 * @param {Object} event the event object from Hangouts Chat
 */
function onMessage(event) {
  if (event.space.type == "DM") {
    var letters = event.message.text
    var words = getWords(letters)
    return { "text": words };
  }
}

function getWords(letters) {
  var URL = 'http://www.anagramica.com/all/:' + letters
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, {"method":"GET"});
  var results = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())["all"];
  var words = ''
  for (var y = 0; y < results.length; y++) {
    words = words + "\n" + results[y]
  }
  return words
}
```

After deploying it, when we message the bot, it is returning virtually no result :(

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: How do you run your your code? From where do you call your functions that expect parameters? Implement logs in your code, so you know in which step the error occurs.

Comment: The code is bring invoked as part of a bot in Google Hangouts Chat and its is supposed to expect the 'words' being entered in the chat room. I did try implementing logs but that didn't record anything when I checked back on the stack driver logs :(

Comment: You can see under View->Logs in the Apps Script Editor logs created with `Logger.log`. You can also see in the console on the side of your browser window logs created with `console.log`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490302/how-can-i-see-the-output-of-console-log

Comment: looks like Logger.log and console.log doesn't work when the function is invoked using a bot :|

Answer (score 0):

If I run `myFunction()` of the following code:

```
function myFunction(){
  var letters='abcd';
  Logger.log(getWords(letters));
}

function getWords(letters) {
  var URL = 'http://www.anagramica.com/all/:' + letters
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, {"method":"GET"});
  var results = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())["all"];
  var words = ''
  for (var y = 0; y < results.length; y++) {
    words = words + "\n" + results[y]
  }
  return words;
}
```

I get the following response:

[image]

The Url fetch request works correctly. Thus, the error must lie in your function `onMessage(event)`.

- Option 1:

  Nothing is returned because the condition `event.space.type == "DM"` is not fulfilled.
- Option 2:

Nothing is returned because `var letters = event.message.text` is not a valid parameter.

Apart from implementing logs as suggested above, you can test what is the origin of your problem by e.g. leaving away the `if` condition or manually defining `letters` as a string.

Does the following work?

```
function onMessage(event) {

    var letters = "test";
    var words = getWords(letters)
    return { "text": words };

}
```

Comment: When I run it on the editor, this works but even after doing everything as indicated, i still don't see a result on my bot :(

Comment: There must be some wrong with the way you call the function from your bot. Maybe it does not pass the event correctly?