# How to copy and apply code from a live demo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle, codepen

I've recently got into coding, and there's a problem that I encounter lots of time. And that is when I'm trying to copy a code from live demo, such as this: https://www.w3resource.com/jquery-exercises/part1/jquery-practical-exercise-17.php

I've tried all kinds of combination, but I can't make it work. I copied all the text provided, yet, why is it not working? Please help me understand how to do this, cause there's a lot of great codes I would to experiment with but can't make it work if it comes from live demos like there's some hidden code not showing up on the codes.

Here's how I tried to do it:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>How to get the value of a textbox using jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="Input text here">
</body>

<script>
$( "input" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var tvalue = $( this ).val();
    console.log(tvalue);
  })
.keyup();
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: How do you place the JavaScript code in the HTML? Do you get any error message?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this and see if you can reproduce the issue there? Can you elaborate more what you have tried or done?

Comment: Hi thank you both for trying to help me. I already updated my question with how I try to do it. I also tried putting the ```<script>``` tags on the ```<head>``` but it still not working. I'm just seeing an ```input box``` but not the function of the script

Comment: It works fine for me. What is your actual problem? If you have a problem with viewing the result of `keyup` you should get to know dev tools better than before

Comment: You are not supposed to see the script code.
The specific code, outputs some text in the console. So you need to open the developer console in your browser and you will see the messages there while you type. See https://javascript.info/devtools

Comment: I'm not seeing the script working for me, like in this demo: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GE788AGFHH81

Comment: It's just showing an input buttons, but not the history logs function of the script

Comment: I updated your question so the script can be run -- without any change to the code. I don't see any problem when running it. Of course, you need to type in the input box to see the logs... Maybe you don't know how to see the console in your browser? Lookup "console in browser" (or just press F12 which opens the console in most popular browsers) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490302/how-can-i-see-the-output-of-console-log

Comment: @TheAuthor see my comment above, i just added a link on how to open the browser developer console.

Comment: Wow! Didn't realize it was not supposed to be seen by users. Thank you so much everyone. One last thing is, how do I make it appear on browser like Google Chrome though? I want to put a special box on my browser so that users can see the history/logs of their inputs.

Comment: I think you're confusing developer tools with the site itself. The console is something you use to develop and diagnose code. To display stuff to users you create a user interface with HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let me go into it step by step.

I assume you know how the rest of your code is working. So I'll only focus on the `script` tag that you provided.

Here it is:

```js
1 $("input").keyup(function() {
2    var tvalue = $(this).val();
3    console.log(tvalue);
4  }).keyup();
```

Let's get into it line by line:

- **line 1:** It contains three different parts the first of them is `$` sign where it exists to **define/access jQuery** (in this case we're accessing something in the DOM). The second part is a selector to "query (or find)" HTML elements (in this case we're going to find an HTML tag which name is `input`). Finally, the third part consists on a jQuery action() to be performed on the element which is a `keyup` action (The keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard, for more information about it you can read [this](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)). Also, we should act something in our keyup action so we need to add a function into it just like the code you provided.
- **line 2:** Within the provided function we got some actions, so in this exact line we're doing two things. First is to **get the queried element value** with this piece of code `$(this).val()` where the first part is accessing the `this` element which is the actual `input` in our case (but I strongly recommend read more about `this` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)) **and in the following we get the value of it** with `val()` (The `val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`. When called on an empty collection, it returns `undefined`.). In the other side of the equation, we got `var tvalue` (`var` is a statement that declares a function-scoped or globally-scoped variable, so we got function-scoped variable `tvalue` here) where it will be `undefined` since the right side of our equation gets evaluated, then **it will fill with the actual value of our input**.
- **line 3:** This is the amazing part of all the code that we got here `console.log(tvalue)`, **`console` itself is not a javascript feature, function or whatever**, (where we have seen some places that it will introduce it as a function within a javascript but it's truly not) **it is the browser API** that provided for javascript and browser for communication. So every browser has a console for you to use when you call such a thing it will be only foundable within your browser dev tools console or in some weird place like IDE terminal (actually when you use SSR's you will found the log into the IDE terminal). So as @Gabriele Petrioli said you can read instruction to access different browsers console in this [link](https://javascript.info/devtools). So whenever you call it you should look for results in the browser console mostly.

  **NOTE:** The `console` object can be accessed from any global object. `Window` on browsing scopes and `WorkerGlobalScope` as specific variants in workers via the property console. It's exposed as `Window.console`, and can be referenced as simply `console`. You can read more about console [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console).
- **line 4:** It is exactly the same as previous `keyup` but it will fire the `keyup` event for the very first time.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it in detail @SMAKKS. It's all clear to me now :)

Comment: @TheAuthor If you have any other trouble with it, just let me know about it.