# How to display name of a choosen item from a list inside an alert window

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angular

i am trying to display the month's name every time the user chooses a month fron the list.
i managed to display an alert but i want to know how can i display the name of the choosen or selected months.
i mean, when the user chooses a month the following text should appear for an example

```
 month choosen is April
```

please let me know how to achieve it

**app.component.html**:

```
<div> Months :
    <select (change) = "changemonths($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let i of months">{{i}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "Jun",
        "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        
 changemonths(event) {
  alert("Changed month from the Dropdown" + event.value);
  console.log(event);
 }
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toqsfs?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.target.value` instead of `event.value`

```
changemonths(event) {
    alert("Changed month from the Dropdown" + event.target.value);
    console.log(event);
}
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hzdewq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: would you please tell me how did you knew that .target.value?i want to know which webpage or site provides such details

Comment: @user2121 You can just look at the event object itself (ie simple `console.log`) and you'll see that the value is located in `target.value`. (see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Comment: please, the log statement in the code i posted above i do not know where its output is...can you please tell me how can i see the output of the log statement

Comment: @user2121 Do you mean `console.log`?

Comment: Just open the browser console (F12). Are you new to JS?

Comment: i opened the console via f12 but nothing is there..yes

Comment: [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp), [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490302/how-can-i-see-the-output-of-console-log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490302/how-can-i-see-the-output-of-console-log)

Answer (score 0):

alert("changed month" + event.target.value);